# Can someone give me the logic of this animated list with timer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I tried to find any flutter package for that but unfortunately, I did not find one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTrrw.png)

Comment: its a static only UI

Answer (score 0):

You can use [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) package, and for each percentage you show a text with check icon as like the image you show.

Comment: how about the down sentences the color change by time